# Background Gradient on Changing height background image

Tags: css

I have a background image that is set to 100% width, depending on the screen size. This means, the height of the background image could be 100px or 800px.

I have a gradient to make the background image slowly transform into a grey color. But because the height of the background varies, I cant figure out how to get the gradient to begin where it is needed.

Setting a % makes it relevant to the page so doesn't work. I figure, I need to use the `calc()` function somehow. This is what i have, any ideas?

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #ddd calc(??)), 
            #ddd url('../img/bg.jpg') no-repeat;
```

Comment: `calc` is not always needed but you need to define the gradient for us to give an answer. Should it start as transparent, change to #ddd at Xpx and then continue to remain #ddd (or) should it start as transparent, stay as transparent till Xpx and then slowly transform into grey color (this is what I assume you need). Also what is the reference point from where Xpx should it be calculated. Is it from the top of the container or the bottom? An answer can be given without all these information but it would be based on assumptions.

Comment: The gradient should do the following

Start as transparent at the top of the page
Transition to #ddd where to bottom of the background image starts

The bottom of the background image could be 100px or 800px depending on the height width of the screen as the background is set to be 100% width